# How to solve 'undefined reference to pow' (already linked with -lm)?

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

I'm using the function `pow()` of `math.h` in my project. **I added the `-lm` flag** to the `Makefile` but I still get the following error trying to run `make`:

```
rudp_comm.c:(.text+0x3c1): undefined reference to `pow'
rudp_comm.c:(.text+0x458): undefined reference to `pow'
```

**How to fix this problem?**

Here's the complete `Makefile`:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O3 -lm
SRC := client/client.c client/client_func.c client/client_func.h server/server.c server/server_func.c server/server_func.h common/conf.c common/conf.h common/file_list.c common/file_list.h common/rudp_comm.c common/rudp_comm.h
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)

.PHONY: all

all: client/client server/server

client/client: client/client.o client/client_func.o common/conf.o common/file_list.o common/rudp_comm.o

client/client.o: client/client.c client/client_func.h common/rudp_comm.h
client/client_func.o: client/client_func.c client/client_func.h common/conf.h common/file_list.h

server/server: server/server.o server/server_func.o common/conf.o common/file_list.o common/rudp_comm.o

server/server.o: server/server.c server/server_func.h common/rudp_comm.h
server/server_func.o: server/server_func.c server/server_func.h common/conf.h common/file_list.h

common/conf.o: common/conf.c common/conf.h
common/file_list.o: common/file_list.c common/file_list.h
common/rudp_comm.o: common/rudp_comm.c common/rudp_comm.h


clean:
        rm -f client/*.o server/*.o common/*.o core

cleanall:
        rm -f client/*.o server/*.o common/*.o core client/client server/server
```

In `rudp_comm.c` of course I included the library (`#include "rudp_comm.h"`), so I really can't guess what the problem could be!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/how-to-fix-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-lm` should go into `LDLIBS`, not `CFLAGS` in the Makefile.

```
LDLIBS = -lm
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

Although, `CFLAGS` is also passed to the compiler, ``-lm`needs to be at the *end* of the commandline. That's why specifying it in`CFLAGS`doesn't work because it needs to be passed at the *linking* stage (specifying`-lm` at the end provides equivalent functionality).

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue! I'll accept it as soon as stackoverflow will allow me to do it :)